# how to retrieve project id from a list of file_id or case_uuid with GDC/TCGA data

Tags: r, bioinformatics

This would have been super easy question, yet I don't know. I have a data.frame in R:
[image]

there's 21000 more rows of these, which I have already downloaded. I would like to know how do I retrieve the project information (project_id and associated biospecimen file) and add columns to the right.

I have tried GenomicDataCommon package, TCGAutils, TCGAbiolinks, none of them give me what I want.
Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected columns

Comment: See if [this](http://127.0.0.1:27776/library/GenomicDataCommons/doc/overview.html) helps. If you don't already, you need to set up user authentication for data download (explained in this link).